# Pronunciation of $M(x)$ and $m(x)$

Tags: soft-question, notation

Suppose I use two functions and I denoted them by lowercase and uppercase letters $m(x)$ and $M(x)$.  Of course, I have to distinguish them somehow.

How do I read this? Is capital/uppercase $M$ of $x$ and lowercase $m$ of $x$ ok?

Comment: My convention's similar to the given answers, except that I use "small" instead of "little". But whatever floats your boat and all that... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, whatever makes you happy and is clear. I would personally, and I feel like this is the most common, read "big M of x" and "little m of x".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alex. After having a look at your profile, I found out I remember you from mathhelpforum. (Which seems be down these days, I do not know, whether it is only temporary problem.)

Comment: Ah, and what was your username on MHF?

Comment: I used the username kompik.

Comment: Ah, were you the one who asked a lot of general topology questions?

Comment: I would say that I tried to _answer_ questions from general topology and set theory. (I cannot recollect asking such a question, but it is of course possible that I asked a few.)

Comment: Haha, I think I do remember you! Well, regardless, I can see that you are well-regarded here. It's good to see you again!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "big em of ex" and "little em of ex". (I am spelling out "em" and "ex" so that I don't have to decide whether to write them uppercase or lowercase.)

In a situation where most other letters occurring were small, I might say "big em of ex" for $M(x)$ and "em of ex" for $m(x)$, but only if I were feeling particularly lazy; this inevitably seems to lead to confusion.